# Error when applying function to list using lmap in R

Tags: r, purrr

I have a list of data frames based on running the following:

```
library(tidyverse)

candidates <- c("A1", "A2", "A3", "B1", "B2")

votes <- function(aa, ab, ba, bb, can) {
  aprob <- c(aa, aa, aa, ab, ab)
  bprob <- c(ba, ba, ba, bb, bb)
  avotes <- t(replicate(25, (sample(can, replace = FALSE, prob = aprob))))
  bvotes <- t(replicate(20, (sample(can, replace = FALSE, prob = bprob))))
  avotes <- as_tibble(avotes)
  bvotes <- as_tibble(bvotes)
  all_votes <- bind_rows(avotes, bvotes)
}

z <- map(1:5, ~ votes(aa = .6, ab = .4, ba = .4, bb = .6, candidates))
```

I am then trying to apply a function to each data frame in the list using lmap:

```
count <- function(x) {
  all_votes <- x %>% 
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = contains("V")) %>% 
    mutate(name = str_remove_all(name, "V")) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = name) %>% 
    select(-rn) %>% 
    mutate_all(as.integer)
}

a <- lmap(z, ~ count)
```

And I get this error:

```
Error in lmap_at(.x, seq_along(.x), .f, ...) : is.list(res) is not TRUE
```

If I pluck one of the data frames from the list and run the count function it works fine, so I know I'm doing something wrong with lmap. Since lmap is meant to apply a function to a list and return a list I assumed that was what I wanted to use here. I have no idea what the error is trying to tell me. I’d appreciate some help on what I’m doing wrong and how to fix it. Entirely possible there is an stupid mistake staring at me and I'm just not seeing it.

I know I could solve this by putting the code from the second function into the first function but I need to separate it out. And I still want to know what I’m doing wrong so I don’t repeat it in the future.

Comment: `map(z, count)` should work and if you are using lambda expression, then you need `~ count(.x))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code, OP's used lambda expression, and not applying the function on the list element.  Based on the function created, it is more suitable for `map`

```
a1 <- map(z, count)
```

or with lambda expression

```
a1 <- map(z, ~ count(.x))
```

---

Regarding the `lmap`, as specified in the documentation

> map(), lmap_at() and lmap_if() are similar to map(), map_at() and map_if(), with the difference that they operate exclusively on
> functions that take and return a list (or data frame). Thus, instead of mapping the elements of a list (as in .x[[i]]),
> they apply a function .f to each subset of size 1 of that list (as in .x[i]). We call those elements list-elements).

Thus, subset is still a `list`.  So, we may need to extract the list element with `[[` as the function 'count' is looking for a `data.frame` as input and not a `list`

```
a2 <- lmap(z, ~ count(.x[[1]]))
```

Note that there is a difference in the structure of output from `map` and `lmap` as `lmap` returns `list` as output, it is a `list` of 25 vectors, while `map` is a `list` of 5 tibble i.e. if we check the output of the first list element of 'a1' and the first five elements of 'a2', it is the same, similarly second element of 'a1' and next five (6:10) of 'a2',...

```
all.equal(unclass(a1[[1]]), a2[1:5], check.attributes = FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain, even thought the solution was just to use map. I will be more likely to understand things in the future. I swear I had tried the regular map before and had issues with it but now it's running just fine.